# Subselect in JPQL

Tags: jpql, cuba-platform

Looking to perform a possible subselect in JPQL.  I use SQL often and looking to perform a query like this:

```
Select ((Select SUM(e.hours.hours) from app$Time e 
where e.type = 'Purchased')
 - 
(Select SUM(f.hours.hours) from app$Time f 
where f.type = 'Used'))
```

I have not seen many examples of JPQL performing a query like this, hoping that this is possible.

Comment: What means the `-` signal in the middle of the query? Are you subtracting the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay,

JPA 2.1 specification doesn't support subquery in the select list.

From the specification:

The SELECT clause can contain one or more of the following elements: an identification variable that
ranges over an abstract schema type, a single-valued path expression, a scalar expression, an aggregate
expression, a constructor expression.

Workaround: you can perform two JPQL queries and subtract the Used from the Purchased in the java code

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I ended up doing.